# Clicking on cross won't make it go away

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making an informative message for the user using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     You're now logged in as <strong>{{ email }}</strong>.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.alert').alert('close');
</script>

<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

When I click on the cross it won't go away. What gives ?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4?  your html seems to work out of the box without any additional jquery: https://www.bootply.com/2Z3NJbMErG

Comment: Isn't bootstrap handling this for you. you don't need this close

Comment: I'm using 4.1.3 ... in the interpreter it works like a charm ... not in my Django template though.

Comment: Could it may be a document ready problem?

Comment: Not much we can do then unless you create a [mcve]

Comment: change the button element to span and it should work

Comment: @Araz . It supposed to be a button not a span element.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by moving Jquery CDN on top of `<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>`.

The Javascript code `$('.alert').alert('close');` was unnecessary hence removed
and the alert goes away now when clicked on the cross.